# Run command line when a document is saved in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: command-line, visual-studio-2013, build-process

I'm currently evaluating using VS2013 for a HTML5 project.

In this project I would like to be able to run a command line tool every time a file is saved (and have the file path passed as argument to the command line tool), and then have the output displayed in the console in VS. It's also important that this setup can be part of the project file, so that when a developer opens the project it's already setup correctly and ready to go without any additional configuring in VS.

In both Sublime Text and Webstorm projects all this is easy to achieve, but I haven't been able to find anything similar in Visual Studio. Any tips would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a DocumentSaved handler with [Visual Commander](http://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) and run a tool. See the "2. Run Cppcheck on the saved file and show results in the Output window" [extension sample](http://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/extensions.html).

Comment: Thank you, this worked well. I still think it's rather weird that VS2013 doesn't have build in support for this.