# Is it possibly to execute a program after saving a file in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, process, build, installation

After editing .less files I save the file in Visual Studio 2013. The new .less file needs to be compiled to a .css before it can be used. I have wrote a program that uses a compiler, but I would like if I can set up VS13 to automatically execute the program each time i save my .less file. Is that possible?

Comment: you can use T4 files.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but it does look like what I need. It makes a new file. I can do that. I need something to automatically run when I save my .less file.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930345/run-command-line-when-a-document-is-saved-in-visual-studio-2013

Answer (score 2):

Use 'Custom Tools' in Visual Studio.

See this references:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166817.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31257/Custom-Tools-Explained

Comment: Looks interesting for sure. A little more work that I would hope for, but I will dig into it a little later, and get back a accept when testing is done, if it did the job.

Comment: Sure, it is not the quickest solution but quite elegant as your created .css file will be automatically embedded in the project as 'subfile' of the .less file. Visual Studio does the same e.g. in creating the .xaml.cs files from .xaml files.

Comment: after my program compiles the .less to a .css, the program moves the .css to another directory. I don't want or need them to be embedded together or the same place.